# Ultragrid/Winforms Grid Hierarchy problem

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagrid, ultrawingrid

I need to create a winforms grid with 3 levels, using infragistics ultragrid.

Level 1 has 2 columns (Fixed)

---> Level 2 has 3 columns (Fixed)

--------> Level 3 has Infinite no of columns (Dynamic based on type of level 2 item)

example

Level 1 Item 1 --> 3 Columns (Fixed)

Level 1 Item 1 --> Level 2 item 1 --> 3 Columns (Fixed)

Level 1 Item 1 --> Level 2 item 1 --> Level 3 Item 1 --> 3 Columns (Dynamic)

Level 1 Item 1 --> Level 2 item 2 --> 3 Columns (Fixed)

Level 1 Item 1 --> Level 2 item 2 --> Level 3 Item 1 --> 6 Columns (Dynamic)

How can this be achieved on the grid, specifically Ultragrid?

I am having a massive headache right now

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UltraGrid uses the concept of "Bands" to store hierarchical data.  Your Level 1 is one band, your Level 2 is another.

Here's where it gets tricky: your Level 3 is actually multiple bands depending on how many dynamic types you have of Level 2 items.

If you're using a DataSet/DataTable as the data source, each DataTable corresponds to a Band, this is simply:

- 1 DataTable for Level 1
- 1 DataTable for Level 2 (with a
  DataRelation back to DataTable 1)
- N DataTables for Level 3, each with
  it's own columns, and each having a
  DataRelation back to DataTable 2

HTH.